# google webfonts: where to find them

Tags: google-webfonts

I have a css code like this

```
      @font-face {
      font-family: "Oswald";
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local("Oswald Regular"), local("Oswald-Regular"), url("http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/-g5pDUSRgvxvOl5u-a_WHw.woff") format("woff");
      }
```

In this code the url shows the location of the .woff file. I want to see are there any more fonts available at `themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/`

when i enter this address `themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/` in the url it says `The requested URL /static/fonts/ was not found on this server.`

SO where can i go in google and see all the available fonts. so that i want to link in the stylesheet and use them.

I searched in google but its not very clear

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+webfonts -> http://www.google.com/fonts D’oh!

Comment: http://bit.ly/1ezufBX

Comment: thank you. But in that how to find the url for any font which i want to use eg:New Rocker and get its .woff url

Comment: Also i want to add Lobster font how to do it

Comment: The search field is in the upper-left corner of http://google.com/fonts

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face 
{   
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/-g5pDUSRgvxvOl5u-a_WHw.eot?') format('eot'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/-g5pDUSRgvxvOl5u-a_WHw.woff') format('woff'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v8/-g5pDUSRgvxvOl5u-a_WHw.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```